# Google Sheets - countif with dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

In `sheet1` have a column with a list of IDs, each with a set of statuses:

```
ID  Apr   May      Jun
1   Load  Load     Complete
2   Load  Complete NA
3   Load  Load     Load
```

In a separate sheet, sheet2 I have a list of the IDs and I am trying to show which of those are complete. My thinking is to use `countif` with a dynamic cell range using the `address` function:

```
=countif("'sheet1'!"&address(row(index('sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,match(A2,'sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,0),1)),3)&":"&ADDRESS(row(index('sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,match(A5,'sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500,0),1))+1,26),"Completed")
```

This formula should find the relevant row for each Id and then check to see whether there are any values of 'Completed' in that row. When combined with an `if` function, this should give an output of the following in `sheet2`:

```
ID Complete
1  Y
2  Y
3  N
```

But at the moment, it is not registering any as complete as the countif formula is returning a 0 for every row.

Is this because `countif` cannot handle dynamic ranges using `address`? If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Please share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it). It's difficult to try to write complex formulas around ideas only. Formulas are based on specifics, and there are too many unknowns. See the spreadsheet, data and full layout (as well as knowing the international locale on the spreadsheet) will provide the answers to those unknowns in the most efficient manner.

Comment: Please share a copy of the spreadsheet, whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, QUERY({A2:A, FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:D),,9^9))}, 
 "select Col1,'Complete' where Col2 contains 'Complete'"), 2, )))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(F2:F="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, QUERY({A2:A, FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:D),,9^9))}, 
 "select Col1,'Y' where Col2 contains 'Complete'"), 2, ), "N")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, please try the following

```
=INDEX({A2:A,IF(A2:A="","",
        (IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,"Complete")=TRUE,"Y","N")))})
```

[image]

*(As always, please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Comment: While this solution worked, I chose @player0 's answer as correct as it was scalable across multiple columns, without having to add the references individually